# Woocommerce API with Python wont remove uncategorized from my products

Tags: python, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

Its bit of spageti code but so far I understand this should remove uncategorized from products that has more than 2 categories.

Maybe I just dont know what I am doing I am bit new at this

```
import json
from asyncio import sleep
import math
import time
from woocommerce import API
from ast import For
from retry import retry
import re
import requests

uncategorized = 15
multiCat = []
catCount = 1
wcapi = API(
    url="",
    
    consumer_key="",
    consumer_secret="",
    version="wc/v3",
    timeout=50,
    # verify_ssl=False,
)
total = wcapi.get("reports/products/totals").json()
totalsimple = int(total[2]["total"])
print("Total Products Currently:", totalsimple)
amountOfPages = totalsimple / 100
print(amountOfPages)
def round_up(n, decimals=0):
    multiplier = 10 ** decimals
    return math.ceil(n * multiplier) / multiplier
amountOfPages = int(round_up(amountOfPages))

products = wcapi.get("products?per_page=100").json()
for product in products:
    categories = product["categories"]
    for category in categories:
        
        category = {"id": category["id"]}
        multiCat.append(category)
        catCount = catCount + 1
    
    if catCount >= 1:
        # print(multiCat)
        try:
            multiCat.remove({"id": uncategorized})
            
        except:
            print("not uncategorized")
        #print(multiCat)
        multiCat2 = {"categories":
            multiCat
        }
        data = {
            "categories": [

            ],

        }
        print(multiCat2)
        productID = str(product["id"])
        print(wcapi.put("products/" + productID, multiCat2).json())
       
        
    catCount = 0
    print(multiCat)
    multiCat = []
    print ("SKU: " + product["sku"])
    print("Price: " + product["price"])
    print("\n")
```

I tried to remove it uncategorized by updating it with out the ID of 15 and I came no where

Answer (score 0):

Well I have done it without using the API using the GUI by creating another default category and removing uncategorized and it fixed my problem I had quickly but I would still like to see if I can do this from the API with a script that I can run

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).